# i m android developer creating db connection using jdbc i successfully add my jar file in studio but why i cannot import forName class?

Tags: java, android, jdbc

here is build.gradle 
**dependencies
{

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar')
```

}**

Comment: As you are adding a JDBC jar in a Android app, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps in Android Studio project structure

> `mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar` this jar file drag and drop to project structure in `app/libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar`
>   Then right click on that jar file and select `Add as Library`
>   after that go to app build.gradle and Sync it.
>   Now it should be work well .you can import any class of JDBC, ...,.....library

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the .jar file into the libs folder in app folder.